# ERROR org.springframework.security.core.SpringSecurityCoreVersion - *** Spring Major version '3' expected, but you are running with version: 2.5.6

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

In My spring MVC project, I am getting the following error.
I just imported the project and resolved the dependencies and trying to run and its not a maven project. Same project is working fine in my office PC. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Here is the snippet of error message:

**<----snip--->**

```
1 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
197 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Jun 04 13:33:30 IST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
316 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml]
1019 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.security.core.SpringSecurityCoreVersion - You are running with Spring Security Core 3.1.0.RELEASE
1019 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.springframework.security.core.SpringSecurityCoreVersion - *** Spring Major version '3' expected, but you are running with version: 2.5.6. Please check your classpath for unwanted jar files.
1019 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN org.springframework.security.core.SpringSecurityCoreVersion - **** You are advised to use Spring 3.0.6.RELEASE or later with this version. You are running: 2.5.6
1019 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.security.config.SecurityNamespaceHandler - Spring Security 'config' module version is 3.1.0.RELEASE
1171 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.security.config.http.FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSourceParser - Creating access control expression attribute 'permitAll' for /login
1171 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.security.config.http.FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSourceParser - Creating access control expression attribute 'hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')' for /web/manage/requests
1171 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.security.config.http.FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSourceParser - Creating access control expression attribute 'hasRole('ROLE_USER')' for /web/**
1212 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.security.config.http.HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser - Checking sorted filter chain: [Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 100, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 200, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 400, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 700, <org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0>, order = 1100, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1500, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1600, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1700, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 2000, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 2100, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 2200, <org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0>, order = 2300]
1281 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.OrderComparator.sort(Ljava/util/List;)V
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:92)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:609)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:381)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:293)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Jun 04, 2014 1:33:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
```

Comment: I checked the version of spring security all are 3.2.0

Comment: You have the wrong spring-version **You are advised to use Spring 3.0.6.RELEASE or later with this version. You are running: 2.5.6 1019 ** You use spring-core and so on 2.5.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see from your error log:

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.OrderComparator.sort(Ljava/util/List;)V`

Which essentially means that the method named "sort" in the "OrderComparator" class in the version of org.springframework.core that you are using does not exist.  After looking at the API for spring-core, I have found that the sort method of OrderComparator was added in version 3.0.0.RELEASE for an array of objects (see [Spring 3.0.0.RELEASE API documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.RELEASE/api/)), i.e.

`static void sort(Object [] array)`

And an additional method for the List type as you are using was introduced in Spring-Core 3.1.0.RELEASE (see [Spring 3.1.0.RELEASE API documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.0.RELEASE/api/)), i.e.

`static void sort(List <?> list)`

tldr; Ensure you are using at least spring-core version 3.1.0.RELEASE.

Answer (score 1):

This is seen when the Spring-core version is not compatible with Spring-security-core version. You may want to check the dependency tree of you project to check what version of Spring libraries are being used. Make sure you have compatible version of spring-core, and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like spring-core version is the wrong one as there is no method with signature OrderComparator.sort(List) in version v2.5.6 of spring-core

You have to use the compatible version of spring-core as well within your project. i.e spring-core-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar